# mutlifile upload client side validation in JSF by javascript

Tags: validation, jsf, file-upload, client

I want multi upload feature in ADF(JSF based) application. I want to do client side validation for size and extension. Can anyone help me doing that. How I can do that.

```
<af:resource type="javascript" source="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"/>
      <af:resource type="javascript">
  $(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){
        var isOk = true;
        $('input[type=file][max-size]').each(function(){
            if(typeof this.files[0] !== 'undefined'){
                var maxSize = parseInt($(this).attr('max-size'),10),
                size = this.files[0].fileSize;
                isOk = maxSize > size;
                return isOk;
            }
        });
        return isOk;
    });
});

    </af:resource>
      <af:form id="f1" usesUpload="true" styleClass="formclass">
        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2">
          <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" layout="vertical"
                               styleClass="AFStrechWidth">
            <af:commandButton text="commandButton 1" id="cb1"/>
            <af:inputFile label="Label 1" id="if1" 
                          maximumFiles="4" uploadType="manualIfMultiple">

            </af:inputFile>
          </af:panelGroupLayout>
        </af:panelGroupLayout>
      </af:form>
    </af:document>
  </f:view>
</jsp:root>
```

Comment: It's in JSF not different from "plain HTML". After all, JSF is just a HTML code generator and JavaScript knows absolutely nothing about JSF (rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*, look that is exactly what JS is seeing). You will have more chance in finding answers if you replace the search keyword "JSF" by "HTML(5)".

Comment: Hi All,  May be I am not very much good in javascript.I tried like

Comment: I am trying like this. Can u help

Comment: When writing JavaScript code, you should not look at JSF source code. You should look at JSF generated HTML output. Rightclick page in browser and do *View Source*.

Comment: Ok.I see. One more question.In javascript. they use styleclass .So for JSF we should use id of component?

Comment: IDs are not abstract/reusable (i.e. when you intend to reuse same functionality on another component, you have to manually edit the JS function to add the new ID, or perhaps even awkwardly copypaste the whole JS function and then edit it). Classes are abstract/reusable (i.e. when you intend to reuse same functionality on another component, just give it the desired class).

Comment: Ok Thanks BalusC for replying i will try that. But can you tell me is this possible with multiple file upload validation using javascript in JSF or ADF. I want to know whther I am doing correctly or no? M on right track?

Comment: I don't do ADF so I can't tell the generated HTML output from top of head. As indicated by the first comment, it all depends on the generated HTML output, not on the JSF source code. As least, it looks like that it would also just generate `<input type="file">` as there's basically no other way to upload a file in HTML (apart from a Flash plugin, but that doesn't seem to be the case either as it would be impossible to manipulate it via JS)